# Call Stored Procedure function not working

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters

I have this stored procedure for saving some values in a row.
The parameters for the stored procedure are:
@StepId (Int)
@DateCalculationRule (Char)
@Result (Int)

my VB code:

```
Private Sub buttonCalculateDatesClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttonCalculateDates.Click
        Dim ok As Integer = 1
        Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnnString").ConnectionString
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SaveStepDeadlineRule", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@StepId", 1648))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DateCalculationRule", "DR01#EXACTDATE"))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Result", 0))
        cmd.Parameters("@Result").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        Try
            conn.Open()
            ok = IIf(IsDBNull(cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value), 1, cmd.Parameters("@Result").Value)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ok = 1
        End Try
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

If I run the procedure directly in data base with @StepId 1648 and some text in @DateCalculationRule it works perfectly. So is something with my  function.
I'm not getting any kind of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the: **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()** after **conn.open()**